# How to use a single returned value if method return set of values

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function readMetaData() {

  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(METADATA_SHEET);
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,2);
  var sprintFixVersion = range.getValue();
  var range = sheet.getRange(2,2);
  var hotfixAndPatchVersion = range.getValue(); 

  Logger.log(sprintFixVersion);
  Logger.log(hotfixAndPatchVersion);

  return {
    "sprintFixVersion":sprintFixVersion,
    "hotfixAndPatchVersion": hotfixAndPatchVersion
  };
}
```

above method returns two value, but while calling a function I need only one value at a time means either sprintFixVersion or hotfixAndPatchVersion. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to access one of those properties it's pretty simple. For example:

```
var hotfixVersion = readMetaData().hotfixAndPatchVersion;
```

Answer (score 0):

Even we can use

```
readMetaData()['hotfixAndPatchVersion']
```